# mapping java enum with hibernate to postges

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

i want to create and add to database user with enum
but cannot create instance
Required type:javax.management.relation.Role

Provided: cinema.entity.Role
how to fix it

user class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;
}
```

enum

```
 public enum Role  {
            USER, MANAGER, ADMIN
    }
```

db
[image]

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cinema</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">user</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>



        <mapping class="cinema.entity.User"/>
        <mapping class="cinema.entity.Film"/>
        <mapping class="cinema.entity.Ticket"/>
        <mapping class="cinema.entity.Role"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

trying to run

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
//  либо в cfg прописать
//        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
//        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ticket.class);
//        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Film.class);

        configuration.configure();

        try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
             Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction(); // начало

            User user = User.builder()
                    .login("ivan@gmal.com")
                    .password("pass")

//            Required type:javax.management.relation.Role
//            Provided: cinema.entity.Role
                    .role(Role.USER) //got an error
                    .build();

            session.save(user);

            session.getTransaction().commit();//конец
        }
    }
}
```

i want to create and add to database user with enum
but cannot create instance
Required type:javax.management.relation.Role

Provided: cinema.entity.Role
how to fix it

Comment: Check your `import`  statements, it seems that you have imported `javax.management.relation.Role` instead of  `cinema.entity.Role`  (possibly in the `User` class).

Comment: @Arnaud THANKS, it helps... make it in answer

Comment: You're welcome, but we consider this rather as a typo here, no need to put an answer :)

Comment: @Arnaud ок. one more time thanks